# JQuery - Clone DIV with button duplicates incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

Fairly new to programming in general, so this might not be pretty.  My problem is when I click the button in the html ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/waynebunch/7rx6526t/))

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(".groupcontainer").clone().appendTo(".groupcontainer");
  });
});
```

it will duplicate the first time perfectly.  Then, as I keep clicking it, the div will duplicate exponentially and the format gets messy.  Also, when it does add to the webpage, the parent div won't expand vertically to allow for the duplicates.

1. Need one duplicate each time the button is pressed (append to itself, if possible???)
2. When it's duplicated multiple times, need the parent div to expand with it.

I'm assuming #1 is because I'm using .groupcontainer to clone and appending it to itself - is that an issue?  Can someone explain how I would clone .groupcontainer and have it append directly below itself?  I've looked around but not seeing the same issue I'm having.

As for #2, does appending this way not allow the parent div to expand?

Am I so far off you want to laugh??

Comment: Yes, every time you click, you find `.groupcontainer` and you clone it.  So when you click the first time, it puts another `.groupcontainer` inside your `.groupcontainer`, you click again, it takes the two group containers and makes it 4, then 8 and so on.  I'll write out something below

Comment: Gotcha.  I get it now after reading all your help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a combination of [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) like so (also note my use of the flags for [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).closest(".groupcontainer");
    target.clone(true, true).appendTo(target.parent());
    // alternatively you can also use .insertAfter() to
    // place the clone after the cloned element rather
    // than at the end of all cloned elements
    // https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/
    /* target.clone(true, true).insertAfter(target); */
  });
});
```

```css
.groupcontainer {
  background-color: white;
  height: 225px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.group {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px;
  color: white;
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
}

.quantity {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}

.system {
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.total {
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.specs {
  float: left;
  width: 648px;
  min-height: 50px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  clear: both;
}

.specs table {
  width: 650px !important;
}

.specs table tr {
  background-color: white !important;
}

.specs table tr td {
  font-family: Arial !important;
  font-size: 9px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
  color: black !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.specs table tr td span {
  color: black !important;
  font-family: Arial !important;
  font-size: 9px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="groupcontainer">
  <div class="group">
    <label for="exampleInputText">Group: </label>
    <input type="text" name="group_1" id="group_1" onchange="updateDue()" />
  </div>

  <div class="quantity">
    <label for="exampleInputText">Quantity: </label>
    <input type="text" name="quantity1" id="quantity1" onchange="updateDue()" />
  </div>

  <div class="total">
    <label for="exampleInputText">System Price:</label>
    <input type="text" name="systemprice" id="systemprice" onchange="updateDue()" />
  </div>

  <div class="system">
    <label for="exampleInputText">Group Total:
      <script type="text/javascript">
        // Library ready to use:
        accounting.formatMoney(5318008);

      </script>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="grouptotal" id="grouptotal" onchange="updateDue()" />
  </div>

  <!--begin the specs here-->

  <div class="specs">

    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>

    <button>Clone all p elements, and append them to the body element</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: var target = $(this).closest(".groupcontainer")

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and explanation, works like a charm.  And now I know a little more about Jquery

Comment: FYI - The insertAfter(target) was what worked perfectly.  When I used the appendTo() it was dropping them at the end of my html.

Comment: @WayneBunch Glad to hear it.  jQuery is very powerful when it comes to DOM manipulation.  If you want to learn more of what it's capable of, I'd suggest glancing over the [manipulation category](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) of their documentation for other useful functions.  jQuery has a very nicely documented site.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to update this in case someone else sees it.  In the end, the best answer:

```
$('#clone').click(function() {
    var target = $('.groupcontainer:last');
    target.clone(true, true).insertAfter(target);
  });
```

$(`.groupcontainer:last`) instead of `$(this).closest(".groupcontainer")` worked nicely because there was no restriction on where the button is.  I neglected to mention in the question that I planned on moving the button.

Comment: Excellent solution. But after cloning the div, added multi select2 boxes are not working!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the first instance of `.groupcontainer` as the page loads.  This will find that single group container and make it a variable.

Then when you click, it will append a new (single instance) group container to your container.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clonedGroupContainer = $('.groupcontainer').clone();
    $('.groupcontainer').click(function(){
        $(this).append(clonedGroupContainer);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Because we're using a single instance of a clone, the DOM thinks there's only one instance and basically it's just moving the clone around (even though it's going to the same place).

So what we have to do is create the clone of the first element right off the bat, then append that to wherever (I just appended to the body for ease) and then we hide it.  It doesn't matter where it is because the element will be hidden (just don't clone it to itself).  Then every time we click, it creates a NEW clone of that object and we can manipulate that new clone every time.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clonedGroupContainer = $('.groupcontainer').clone();
    $('body').append(clonedGroupContainer);
    clonedGroupContainer.addClass('clone').hide();
    $(document).on('click', '.groupcontainer', function(){
        var clonedGroupContainer2 = $('.clone').clone();
        $(this).append(clonedGroupContainer2);
        clonedGroupContainer2.removeClass('clone').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, you can do it that way.  I'd have to test both ways.  For now, let's just make it the clone

Comment: Thanks!  This works, but only once.  After that initial clone, the button doesn't create new clones.  I don't get it, code looks pretty straight forward to me.

Comment: @WayneBunch, Very strange indeed.  I've made a fiddle to try it out and it's acting very weird. : https://jsfiddle.net/ru7s58jp/

Comment: @WayneBunch, Ok, I've made a workaround - here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ru7s58jp/1/  I will update the answer to reflect

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the whole class `.groupcontainer` and `$(".groupcontainer")` will actully return you an array with all elements from this class. Why don't you try selecting an element by it's Id. This way you will select only one element and cloning it shouldn't be a probelm.

Comment: Thanks for the input!  The only issue with this that I can see is I'd have to select six elements the way I have it setup.  I'm not sure if this is fact, just my thoughts.  Classes:  groupcontainer, group, quantity, total, system and specs would all need to be selected and cloned, correct?

Comment: No, you just need to select the parent node and .clone() will clone all it's children Nodes.
See the official documentation: https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Even better, if you use the function .clone() and add the parameters true `.clone(true, true)` this should make a deep copy of the element. this mean that it will copy all it's events and all its children's events. This way you should be able to click on the new element and it will make a new copy, just like the first one

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$('.groupcontainer')` grabs *all* elements with a class of `groupcontainer`. You can grab the most recent one by using [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) then use [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to get the parent of the `.groupcontainer`s and append to that.

```
var $groupContainer = $('.groupcontainer');
$groupContainer.last().clone().appendTo($groupContainer.parent());
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  However, upon button click, this doesn't create the cloned element on the page.  Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

the time you select the container inside the click handler is essential.
On the first click, there's only one container and you clone it and append it to itself.
With the second click you have two containers. You select both, and append both to themselves, leading to an exponential behaviour.

Restrict your selector to only one or store your first container in a reference variable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $container = $('.groupcontainer');

    $container.find('button').click(function() {
        $container.clone().appendTo($container);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this out but the button doesn't cause it to clone, at least on the page.  It seems this creates `var $container` but doesn't correctly append to $container.